How do I produce an analog output from an Arduino Mega and connect it to a PLC's analog input card? PWM and LM6211 Op-amp or arduino module?
I want to produce a linear output from an Arduino Mega that will be read by a PLC.
Here’s the setup: I use the Arduino to control a 24V sensor through the MAX31915 evaluation kit, which translates the sensor's 24V signal to 5V. I then want to produce a linear output (like a percentage) based on the sensor's readings. This output needs to be sent to a PLC, so I require another voltage translation from 5V to 24V.
In my area, the most commonly used PLCs are Siemens S7-1200 and S7-1500. I plan to use a PLC model with high-speed counters if needed.
I initially considered using the LM6211 op-amp to amplify the 5V signal to 24V. However, I learned that the Arduino Mega does not have a DAC module. I found a thread suggesting a PWM and RC circuit as a potential solution:
Potential Solution Thread
I’m exploring how to apply this approach to my setup. My current options are:

Finding a suitable topology for the LM6211 with a DAC module to handle the amplification.
Using a DAC module designed for 24V output, such as this one: DFRobot DAC Module.

The LM6211 op-amp has a rail-to-rail output swing, but I’m struggling with the circuit design needed to achieve a 24V output.
Here’s the link for the MAX31915 eval kit that I use for the 24V to 5V translation.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :D

Some PLCs can take pulse-width or pulse-counting directly as an input. Is that an option here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why do you need a voltage translation from 5->24V? You could do a regular 4 wire 4-20 mA current loop output in sink mode, then your 24V system voltage can be the supply voltage.

I'm terribly sorry I did not know the 4 wire 4-20 mA current loop output existed. I'll try to get familiar with it, after your suggestion.

After reading a bit of stuff on the 4-20 mA current loop, the reason why I think it may not work is because the arduino is needed to interpret the sensor signal into a percentage value, and since I can't power the arduino with 24v that's not good. I can see why working with a PLC from the start would be beneficial, but I don't have access to a PLC currently or for the foreseeable future.

(If you @- tag me in the comments, I get a notification that you replied) || No, 4-20 mA will for sure work. That's how measurements are communicated to PLCs in industrial plants all over the world. You don't need to power the Arduino from 24V to use 4-20 mA in Sink mode. (You could also do source mode current loop, but then you're more limited wrt what impedance you can use in the PLC AI card



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You can implement a PWM driven constant current sink like this. That allows you to communicate your measured signal mapped from 0-100% Full Scale reading, to 20-100% duty cycle, corresponding to 4-20 mA.
This way your signal level will not be impacted by the impedance of the cable you use for communication (within reasonable limits), and you will not have to use a 5 V to 24 V boost converter to supply the voltage to your signal.
NB:

This is just a suggested circuit, component values likely need tweaking to fit your application.
It is important that the Arduino and PLC power supply has the same 0V.
To use in a proper industrial environment, sprinkle with the appropriate protection components for EMC.

